# Correct function remove special characters

Tags: php, xml

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

Currently I have above function but I have result:
`Hugo-Boss-The-Scent-For-Her-Eau-De-Perfume-Spray-50ml`

When I edit

```
str_replace('®', 'a', $string);
```

then 4711EauDeCologne800ml

How to add space?

I need get result:
`Hugo Boss The Scent For Her Eau De Perfume Spray 50ml`

I need only remove:
@^%*$*#   śćó ©

Code above.  Can any one help me correct this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your needs correctly, One of the ways:

Change to

```
<?php
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

   $string2= preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

   return  str_replace('-', ' ', $string2); // Replaces all hyphens with spaces.
}

// echo clean("Hugo Boss The Scent For Her Eau De Perfume Spray 50ml ®®®");

?>
```